# Unity, How to use AsEnumerable

Tags: unity-game-engine, system.data, system.data.datatable, asenumerable

I need to use `AsEnumerable()` on a `DataTable` in Unity, but it seems the Unity version of `System.Data` doesn't have that method!

[image]

I tried to import the VS version of dll into the asset, but it told me that `Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported`.

Could somebody please be so kind and teach me what should I do!?

Much appreciated!

Comment: It's in the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: I "DID" using System.Linq! Didn't work!

Comment: Then you should show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `AsEnumerable()` is an extension fo the class `Datatable`, you need to add the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` into your assets.

Comment: It told me `Loading assembly failed: "Assets/Plugins/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"`. What should I do!?

Comment: I'm using 2018.4.5f1.

Comment: Are you using unity hub? you can try to install a newer version and update your project easily, with my version it works

Comment: I'm sorry! I imported the "wrong" dll! I imported the VS version of DataSetExtensions.dll! Once I changed it to unity version from Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0, it worked like a charm! Thanks! :)